# How to close some terminals In Ubuntu in one time?

Tags: command-line

If I use right mouse click to Icon I still need to confirm closing
Can use script, or command or utility
Kindly advise

Comment: No such option possible for Right-click quit if the terminal is running some other program, or an SSH session, or some command is still pending.

Answer (score 1):

When the terminal is asking you to confirm, it’s because it’s running another process.

Example, type the command `top` in a terminal. It will run the `top` utility.
To quit, you should first press the "Q" key and then close your terminal.

You need to kill the child process before the parent process. In other words, quit the application you launched with the terminal first and then close the terminal.